# Send value to another page

Tags: php

I created a table to show the search results, each row the table is a link and the links have a hidden form with a javascript to send the id to another php page, but the problem is when I click one of this links, the form only sends the first id the sql table. After all What's wrong ?

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 

        echo("<form id=id_form method=post action=lp_search_system_2.php>
        <input type=hidden name=id value=".$row['id_np_outdoor'].">
        </form>");

        echo '  <tr align="left" class="simple">
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="id_form.submit()">' . $row['nome'] . '</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="id_form.submit()">' . $row['sobrenome'] . '</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="id_form.submit()">' . $row['tipo'] . '</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="id_form.submit()">' . $row['estado'] . '</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="id_form.submit()">' . $row['país'] . '</a></td>
                </tr>

             ';

}
                echo "</table>";
```

Comment: maybe share the javascript to so we can see what is wrong

Comment: all onclick will do the same things? show js

Comment: don't know if it will fix your problem but you should have quotes around your form and input attributes.

Comment: I showed all javascript in this code.

Comment: dude, all the forms has same id. So, give different id/name to each form and then it will work.

Comment: @Bhavik Shah how I do to put a different name in each form generated into the while ?

Comment: i have posted an answer. refer it and ask if it still doesnt work.

Comment: heay dude, has it helped? i want to delete the answer. It was just for your sake of understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your time!!! helped, but still doesn't work, but now it's better

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    echo "<form id=id_form".$row['id or something'] method=post action=lp_search_system_2.php>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=id value=".$row['id_np_outdoor'].">";
    echo "</form>";
    :
    :
    :
    as you have made it.
```

Remember, you will also have to submit the **respective** form for each row. So, change onclick code too..